# What is the file location for ip routes in RHEL9?

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, routing, networkmanager

My route table on RHEL9 looks as below:

```
root@localhost network-scripts]# netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens160
10.0.0.0        192.168.1.1     255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 ens160
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens160
```

In the previous version of RedHat the route table entries are stored in a file under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` 
 
However, in `RHEL9` I don't see any files in the directory `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`

**What is the file location for ip routes in RHEL9?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in RHEL 8, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` was deprecated.

Network configuration in RHEL 8 and later is managed using Network Manager. You will find the corresponding configuration files in the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directory. You can manipulate routes using the `nmcli` command, the Network Manager GUI, or by directly editing these files.

There are some examples of using `nmcli` [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configuring_static_routes_using_nmcli).